# PyOpenGL installation on macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, opengl

I am trying to install PyOpenGL on my MacBook Pro 16" for distant studies at university. I am running macOS Big Sur however I read that this OS version could cause problems with OpenGL.

I have tried this command for the installation:

`pip3 install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate`

Everything seems to be correctly installed in my python packages. But when I try to import the necessary packages in python3 with this command : `from OpenGL.GLUT import *`  I get a strange error.

[image]

I have searched on internet, but I couldn’t find any recent and working installation process.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Thomas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the:
[Unable to import opengl.gl in python on macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63475461/unable-to-import-opengl-gl-in-python-on-macos)
Check the second answer (the first will only fix OpenGL.GL but not OpenGL.GLUT).

You need to set:

fullName = "/System/Library/Frameworks/{}.framework/{}".format(name,name)

in the file OpenGL/platform/ctypesloader.py (the exact absolute location depends on your installation).

Yuval.